# Batch message processing from Azure Storage Queue to Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

What I want to know is if I can grab, let's say, 1000 messages from Storage queue and process them in single Azure Function run.

I am building a system that will merge the messages data of, let's say, 1000 messages to a json format and send it somewhere. However, the messages are arriving a hundred thousand per minute.

I am thinking to put those messages first in a queue and grab them per batch and the merge the data of each batch.

To consider for the possible solution:

1. A batch must be processed within a second or less. This is to be used for a real-time application. So, processing of the messages should be as quick as possible.

## Added

Another solution comes to my mind for my system is to save these messages to folders separated by time (per second timestamp). Then, the function will just combine the data from each folder.

My question here are:

1. Is this possible?
2. Is this a time-effective solution?
3. What resources are better to use for this solution?
   ==-

If you have other solutions like using other Azure resources (Note: I am a newbie in Azure world and not familiar of what resources is better cause there are so many). This will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a single Azure Function it is not possible to do so simply because the maximum number of messages that can be fetched in a single batch/request from an Azure Storage Queue is 32.

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-messages#uri-parameters):

[image]

What you could possibly do is make use of [`Azure Durable Functions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp) and implement [`Fan-In Pattern`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#fan-in-out) where each instance of your Function will fetch 32 messages from the queue and then send it to an aggregator Function which will merge data from each individual Function fetching messages from the Storage Queue.

Comment: This is a really great idea. I will be implementing this and will get back to this comment once done. Thank you so much.

Comment: Question, will the get request automatically delete the messages from the queue or I need to delete it using delete request? If not the first case, If the Function instances run in parallel, it could possibly fetch the same data twice. Am I right?

Comment: `will the get request automatically delete the messages from the queue or I need to delete it using delete request?` - Azure Function Runtime should take care of this for you assuming your Azure Function is a Queue Triggered Function. Otherwise you will need to take care of it. `If the Function instances run in parallel, it could possibly fetch the same data twice. Am I right?` - No, if a message is dequeued it won't be visible to other callers. In other words, a message can only be fetched by a single Function instance.